# CORS error on AKS after updating SSL certificate

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have updated the SSL certificates on my AKS service. But I am getting CORS error.
New certificates are getting reflected though.
Can someone provide a solution for it.
Here is the TLS part of my ingress file.

```
spec:
  tls:
   - hosts:
     - "prodazure.thesolarlabs.com"
     secretName: tls-secret
```

Comment: Can you show a simple and a CORS request performed with curl or httpie showing request and response headers?

Answer (score 1):

A [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error is related to the fact that you are issuing a request (fetch, XHR, ...) from a Javascript origin to another service, the destination/backend, and the origin service is not allowed to according to the headers provided by that destination service.

It means that your service, the origin, the one deployed in AKS, is trying contacting another service. In order to avoid the CORS errors, that service needs to provide an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` that at least includes the host for the origin service, in your example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://prodazure.thesolarlabs.com
```

Changing a SSL certificate by itself shouldn't be the cause of the CORS error: please, as mentioned, adapt your destination/backend service CORS configuration to point to the new host of the origin service, if you changed it, and be sure that you are configuring `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for the right HTTP scheme, `https` in this case, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it took me a while to figure out. Might not be the same exact issue but maybe someone else can find it useful.

In my case, we are running AKS with AGIC and an application gateway provisioned with AKS. Backend is downstream of a CDN_Frontdoor. Whenever tls with cert-manager and letsencrypt is set up in the cluster, CORS error appears as No “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” header present but everything works well without tls in the aks clusters.

It turned out to be an issue where once tls is configured, appgw modifies listener to listen on only “443”. So the fix for me was to manually configure an http listener that’s redirected to the https listener. So if your frontend is configured to send only http requests to the backend, that might be your smoking gun.

Also ensure host name consistency across the reverse proxy you are using.